# WinRT - border hover change opacity

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

I would like to add a hover effect to the border that I've created as below.

```
<Border x:Name="borderHeader" Background="#000000" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="top" Opacity="0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1366">
```

And my visual state code as below.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="borderHeader"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

How ever it's not working.
Please advise which part I have did wrongly.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Visual states can be applied to those controls which are inside `ControlTemplate`. Border is stand alone control. So you need to rely on `PointerEntered` & `PointerExited` events.

XAML

```xml
<Border x:Name="borderHeader" Background="Yellow" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="top" Opacity="0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1366"
                PointerEntered="borderHeader_PointerEntered_1" PointerExited="borderHeader_PointerExited_1"/>
```

C#

```
private void borderHeader_PointerEntered_1(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    borderHeader.Opacity = 1;
}

private void borderHeader_PointerExited_1(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    borderHeader.Opacity = 0.5;
}
```